# Rails 3.1 Asset Pipeline and Third Party JS Calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, javascript, asset-pipeline

I am working on a Rails 3.1 Application, and it contains a third party JS Calendar Picker (jsDatePick). jsDatePick has a whole stack of images that are in images/calendar/img/.

Running rake assets:precompile precompiles them all, but the library still looks for the images in images/calendar/img (not assets/calendar/img). I could change the directory to assets/calendar/img, but it doesn't append the fingerprint hash.

Thoughts on how to resolve an issue like this?

Here is a sample of some of the CSS that goes along with this JS lib:

```
.JsDatePickBox .boxLeftWall .leftTopCorner{ margin:0; padding:0; width:7px; height:8px; background:url(/assets/calendar/img/boxTopLeftCorner.png) left top no-repeat;  overflow:hidden; }
.JsDatePickBox .boxLeftWall .leftBottomCorner{ margin:0; padding:0; width:7px; height:8px; background:url(/assets/calendar/img/boxBottomLeftCorner.png) left top no-repeat;  overflow:hidden; }
.JsDatePickBox .boxLeftWall .leftWall{ margin:0; padding:0; width:7px; background:url(/assets/calendar/img/boxSideWallPx.gif) #ffffff left top repeat-y; overflow:hidden; }
```

While I definitely see a problem here (asset tags should be used, as these images don't exist in the asset folder without the fingerprint hash), some of the images I am specifically looking for are not in any CSS file in the application. I'm looking now to determine where they are being called.

It looks like the other images are applied via the javascript. Here is an example:

```
if (parseInt(aDayDiv.getAttribute("isToday")) == 1){
            this.setC(aDayDiv, "dayDownToday");
            aDayDiv.style.background = "url(" + this.oConfiguration.imgPath + this.oConfiguration.cellColorScheme + "_dayDown.gif) left top no-repeat";
        } else {
            this.setC(aDayDiv, "dayDown");
            aDayDiv.style.background = "url(" + this.oConfiguration.imgPath + this.oConfiguration.cellColorScheme + "_dayDown.gif) left top no-repeat";
        }
```

The oConfiguration.imgPath is defined as such:

```
g_jsDatePickImagePath = "/assets/calendar/img/";

this.oConfiguration.imgPath = (g_jsDatePickImagePath.length != null) ? g_jsDatePickImagePath : "/images/calendar/img/";
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: is there any css that rendered these images ? Paste it here

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to upgrade to Rails 3.1.1+ (I upgraded to rails 3.1.2) and the issue is resolved by Rails running rake assets:precompile:nondigest which results in nondigested versions of assets.